# BEGIN TRAN cause php sqlsrv return empty

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

This is strange, when I have the "begin tran" in the sp, it won't return any row, but if taken away, it works fine. Why is it so ? I am using codeigniter sqlsrv db driver.

**sp**

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_test] @MembershipId int, @CardNumber varchar(50) as

begin tran
select 'hello world' hi
commit tran
```

**php**

```
$sql = sprintf("EXEC [sp_test] @MembershipId=0,@CardNumber=123");       
$query =  $this->oDb->query($sql);
print_r($query->result());
```

Comment: Why do you need a transaction if you only have 1 select statement?

Comment: This is a very simplified sp and does not reflect the real sp that I have with multiple statement. This is just to show the problem.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you have a corresponding `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` later in your SP?

Comment: Yes I do have, just edited the sp. It still not returning any row.

Comment: OK, is your actual stored procedure returning any results when you directly run it from SSMS or wherever?

Comment: Yes, direct Execute in SQL management studio does return

Comment: I think it has to do with that php sqlsrv library?

Comment: When run in SSMS, is there any message or text at all returning before your desired result set? (Run it in Text mode to be sure; if the column headers aren't on the very first line, something else is being returned.) If so, that can get in the way of the database driver interpreting the response-- either causing it to be invalid or buried as a secondary result set.

Comment: Hi thanks for your analysis. I tried to query and result to text. The data look okay. What you meant by column headers ? I got column name on the first line, next line '-------' , then next line 'hello world'

Comment: OMG, the solution is so simple, take away the EXEC in the query. so should be this $sql = sprintf("[sp_test] @MembershipId=0,@CardNumber=123");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who may face this issue, the solution is so simple.

DON'T USE EXEC in the query, so should be this

```
$sql = sprintf("[sp_test] @MembershipId=0,@CardNumber=123");
```